# using sum function in dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use sum function inside dplyr's mutate function. However I am ending up with unexpected results. Below is the code to reproduce the problem

```
chk1 <- data.frame(ba_mat_x=c(1,2,3,4),ba_mat_y=c(NA,2,NA,5))
```

I used the below code to create another column that sums up the above 2 columns

```
chk2 <- chk1 %>% dplyr::mutate(ba_mat=sum(ba_mat_x+ba_mat_y,na.rm = T))
```

I had used `na.rm=T` because I have `NA`s in variable `ba_mat_y`. The result I got is as below

```
        ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
   1        1       NA     13
   2        2        2     13
   3        3       NA     13
   4        4        5     13
```

However, the expected result is

```
      ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
1        1       NA     1
2        2        2     4
3        3       NA     3
4        4        5     9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have multiple columns and want to sum only limited columns we can replace them with 0 and then add the columns

```
library(dplyr)

chk1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ba_mat_x,ba_mat_y), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
  mutate(ba_mat = ba_mat_x + ba_mat_y)

#  ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
#1        1        0      1
#2        2        2      4
#3        3        0      3
#4        4        5      9
```

We can also use `replace_na` from `tidyr` which does the same thing.

```
chk1 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ba_mat_x, ba_mat_y), tidyr::replace_na, 0) %>%
  mutate(ba_mat = ba_mat_x + ba_mat_y)
```

---

If we want to use `sum` other option is to use `purrr`'s `pmap` or `pmap_dbl` where we can now pass list of columns to add upon and then use `sum`.

```
chk1 %>%
  mutate(ba_mat = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(ba_mat_x, ba_mat_y), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) 

#  ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
#1        1       NA      1
#2        2        2      4
#3        3       NA      3
#4        4        5      9
```

In this particular case, we can also use `map2_dbl`

```
chk1 %>%
  mutate(ba_mat = purrr::map2_dbl(ba_mat_x, ba_mat_y, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This would also work since we have only two columns but in case if there are more columns it is better/safer to use `pmap` option.

---

Moreover, as far as your attempt is concerned it would work if you add `rowwise` to it. `rowwise` as the name suggests does all the operation in row-wise fashion.

```
chk1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ba_mat = sum(ba_mat_x, ba_mat_y, na.rm = T))
```

But `rowwise` is usually slower.

Answer (score 2):

You want rowSums, to get the sum of columns for each row.

```
> chk1 %>% dplyr::mutate(ba_mat = rowSums(., na.rm=T))

  ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
1        1       NA      1
2        2        2      4
3        3       NA      3
4        4        5      9
```

Your other formulation (`sum(ba_mat_x+ba_mat_y,na.rm = T))`) means:

- first perform `chk1$ba_mat_x + chk1$ba_mat_y`: `1 + NA, 2 + 2, 3 + NA, 4 + 5`, which results in `NA, 4, NA, 9`
- then take the `sum(na.rm=T)` of that, which is `13`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I understand your answer. I just replicated a simple example. But consider I have other columns such as ba_inns_x and ba_inns_y and I want the sum of those 2 as a new column called ba_inns. In that case, I cannot use rowSums.. Right ? That's why I thought of using sum function. What else can you suggest ?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` from `base R`

```
chk1$ba_mat <- rowSums(chk1, na.rm = TRUE)
chk1
#   ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
#1        1       NA      1
#2        2        2      4
#3        3       NA      3
#4        4        5      9
```

---

Or using `tidverse` while keeping the original columns as such

```
library(tidyverse)
chk1 %>% 
    mutate(ba_mat  = replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
                     reduce(`+`))
#    ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
#1        1       NA      1
#2        2        2      4
#3        3       NA      3
#4        4        5      9
```

Or with `case_when`

```
chk1 %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, list(new = ~case_when(is.na(.) ~ 0,
                TRUE ~ .))) %>%
    transmute(!!! rlang::syms(names(chk1)), ba_mat = ba_mat_x_new + ba_mat_y_new)
#   ba_mat_x ba_mat_y ba_mat
#1        1       NA      1
#2        2        2      4
#3        3       NA      3
#4        4        5      9
```